# PHP contact form receving from all senders apart from @yahoo accounts

Tags: php, apache

I have created a php contact form and for the most part it seems to work fine apart from when the sender is using a @yahoo email address.  I have tested with hotmail and gmail addresses and all are being rceived OK.

I have used PHPMailer in order to try and avoid such problems but it still doesnt not seem to work.

Any help would be great and if you could provide example code that would be awesome!

as a side note - I am hosting the index.php file through godaddy (not sure if this could be causing an issue)

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

    function sendemail ($to, $from, $body) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->setFrom($from);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form - Email';
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->IsHTML(false);

        return $mail->send();
    }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    if (sendemail('example@gmail.com', $email, $subject, $body)) {
        $msg = 'Email has been sent, thank you!';
    } else 
        $msg = 'Email failed, please try again later';       

    }

?>
```

```
<title>Test Contact Form Using PHPMailer</title>

<body>

    <div id="contactInnerWrapper">
        <a href="#"><span id="close">&times;</span></a>
        <h1 id="h1contactForm">Get in touch</h1>
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
                <input  type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter email" id="email">
                <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input  type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><br>
                <label for="body">What would you like to ask us?</label><br>
                <textarea  type="text" name="body" rows="7" id="content"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <br><br>
            <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling SMPT in phpmailer?

Comment: See the information from Yahoo on "Bulk email industry standards and best practices". Yes, this applies to you, the bottom three items are the most important. See: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/practices-senders-sln3435.html

Comment: Yomisimie - I have tried with SMPT enabled but there seems to be an issue with hosting through godaddy.  Any suggestions, ideas, lifelines?

Comment: To be honest, sending mail had become such a headache for me, I ran into similar problems like you have on a weekly basis, solved one problem and then another popped up, that I now use a commercial 3rd party, with an API, to send email. See a list here: https://konghq.com/blog/list-of-10-email-apis If you go for something like this you should really test them first because there are big differences between how they work, what they allow, and how much they cost (lowest level is often free). Then again you might not want to spend any money on sending mail. It's up to you.